# Change tile switch speed in Windows C# Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, live-tile

I have set up 5 tiles in a queue so they are randomly shown on the Windows Start screen.

Just on the right of my app I placed the Windows Store and Facebook app. I noticed that their tile changes much faster than mine, even if all 3 apps have the same amount of different tiles (which is 5 and the maximum of allowed tiles).

Is there a way to influence the behavior of the tiles?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to influence the behavior of the tiles.

The only thing I think of is that they could be different tile templates which could infer a different update time.

Comment: I also guessed that, but it is still weird that the FB and Store App tiles change so fast...

Comment: Agreed, I'd try running an experiment where you're using the same tile templates as Facebook and see if they match then.